# Construct grammar $\ a^i b^j c^{i+j} b^j a^i $

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I've been going through old exams at my college and I found this problem that I haven't yet been able to solve.

Construct grammar defined on the alphabet $\ \{{a, b, c}\} $ which generates strings of the form $\ a^i\ b^j\ c^{i+j}\ b^j\ a^i\  where\ i, j \geq 0. $ It doesn't say anything which form the grammar should be; that is it can be context-free, restricted, unrestricted... anything goes.

Comment: I think the pumping lemma can be used to show that the language is not context-free.  You should focus your efforts any trying to show that it can be represented by a restricted/context-sensitive grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to TY\\
&T\to aTA\mid U\\
&U\to bUB\mid ZV\\
&VB\to Wb\\
&bW\to Wb\\
&ZW\to cZV\\
&Vb\to bV\\
&VA\to Xa\\
&aX\to Xa\\
&bX\to Xb\\
&ZX\to cZV\\
&VY\to C\\
&aC\to Ca\\
&bC\to Cb\\
&ZC\to\lambda
\end{align*}$$

$Y$ marks the end of the string. $T$ generates something of the form $a^nUA^n$; the $A$s will eventually become $a$s. The $U$ generates something of the form $b^mZVB^m$; the $Z$ marks where the $c$s will go, and the $B$s will eventually become $b$s. At this point we have $b^ma^nZVA^nB^mY$.

The $V$ runs across the string to the right until it encounters a $B$; it turns that into a $b$ and turns itself into $W$, which runs back to the left until it hits the $Z$. At that point it deposits a $c$ to the left of the $Z$ and turns back into a $V$. The $V$ runs to the right through any $b$s that have been produced until it hits either a $B$ or an $A$. In the former case it behaves as previously described. In the latter it turns the $A$ into an $a$ and itself into $X$. The $X$ then runs left through $a$s and $b$s until it hits the $Z$, at which point it deposits a $c$ to the left of the $Z$ and turns into a $V$.

Eventually the $V$ running to the right must hit the $Y$. We collapse the $VY$ to $C$, which runs left until it encounters the $Z$, and the $C$ and $Z$ undergo mutual annihilation.

Comment: Great idea, many thanks for the assistance. :)

Comment: @RascalJukka: You’re welcome. The idea of using non-terminal symbols to run back and forth carrying information comes in handy quite often when you’re not dealing with a context-free grammar.

Comment: I had a similar approach, but somehow I feel like I lack in experience and/or practice with these kind of problems, so I couldn't really find a way to solve it.